# SDL2 window does not work when out of focus

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I wanted to create a rectangle constantly running across the window. Turns out the rectangle moves only when i feed the window with any input (floating the cursor around it or pressing keys). Is there a way to make it run non-stop?

Code for the running rectangle:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL.h>


const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
SDL_Window *gWindow = nullptr;
SDL_Renderer *gRenderer = nullptr;

bool init()
{
    bool in = true;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)<0)
    {
        printf("SDL_ did not init, %s", SDL_GetError());
        in = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1"))
        {
            printf("linear texture filtering boned.\n");
            in = false;
        }
        else
        {
            gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("CELLULA_CHARLIE", 1000, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_ALWAYS_ON_TOP);
            if (gWindow == nullptr)
            {
                printf("gwindow did not load, %s", SDL_GetError());
                in = false;
            }
            else
            {
                gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
                if (gRenderer == nullptr)
                {
                    printf("main renderer failed loading, %s", SDL_GetError());
                    in = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
                    int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
                    if (!(IMG_Init(imgFlags)&imgFlags))
                    {
                        printf("Img did not init,  %s", IMG_GetError());
                        in = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return in;
}


void close()
{
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    //gMap = nullptr;
    gWindow = nullptr;
    gRenderer = nullptr;
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char*args[])
{
    int i = 0;
    SDL_Rect rectangle;
    rectangle.h = rectangle.w = 32;
    rectangle.x = rectangle.y = 0;

    if (!init())
    {
        printf("init failed\n");
    }
    else
    {

        bool quit = false;
        SDL_Event e;
        while (!quit)
        {
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
            {
                if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }

                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
                SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);


                rectangle.x = i * 32;
                rectangle.y = rectangle.x;
                i++;
                if (rectangle.x>500)
                {
                    i = 0;
                }
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
                SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &rectangle);

                SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
            }

        }
    }

    //the end//
    close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your main loop code should be after the `while(SDL_PollEvent())` loop, not inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is centered around events. If the window does not have focus it won't receive any input events and that's often all the events you get.

You have options.

1. set up a timer to inject a custom event at regular intervals that would drive your loop when no other events are received.
2. let the loop not be dependent on events, but just run continuously and then inside the loop check if there happen to be events to process and if not, do other stuff.